# No module named django.conf.urls.defaults

Tags: python, django

I'm having some trouble building a django app while following the guide here: https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/searchengine

Hardware/Software:

Django Version 2.1.4
Python Version 3.7
Windows 10 Lenovo Yoga 720

When inputting the following code:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

urlpatterns = patterns('',
(r'^/?$', 'google.searchengine.views.search'),
)
```

into the urls.py, the command line returns:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x03D341E0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Konjo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Konjo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\Konjo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 379, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Users\Konjo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 366, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Konjo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 71, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\Konjo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\Konjo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\Konjo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 396, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\Konjo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 37, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Konjo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 533, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\Konjo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 37, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Konjo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 526, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\Konjo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Konjo\konjo_search\konjo_search\urls.py", line 23, in <module>
    from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.conf.urls.defaults'
```

From multiple rounds of troubleshooting, searching, and testing it looks like some of the modules are either missing or were changed in newer versions of django.  Any help with this matter would be greatly appreciated.

***UPDATE***

Have downgraded to Python 2.7.10 and Django 1.11.17.

View of file structure: [file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qtSi.png)

New error:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x0000000004060CF8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 124, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 359, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 346, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 16, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 26, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 256, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 407, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 400, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\Konjo\google\google\urls.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
ImportError: No module named defaults
```

-Konjo

Answer (score 3):

The module `from django.conf.urls.defaults import *` was removed from Django.

You can do:

```
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = path('',
    (r'^/?$', google.searchengine.views.search),
)
```

Comment: Returns:

 File "C:\Users\Konjo\konjo_search\konjo_search\urls.py", line 20, in <module>
    urlpatterns = path('', 'google.searchengine.views.search')
  File "C:\Users\Konjo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 73, in _path
    raise TypeError('view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().')
TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().

Comment: Where is your `view.py` located?

Comment: views.py is located under the searchengine folder.

Returns: File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\Konjo\google\google\urls.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.urls import path
ImportError: cannot import name path

Answer (score 0):

`django.conf.urls.defaults` has been removed in Django . If the problem was in your own code, you would fix it by changing the import to

```
from django.urls import include, path


urlpatterns = path('', 'google.searchengine.views.search'),
```

)

Comment: Returns:

 File "C:\Users\Konjo\konjo_search\konjo_search\urls.py", line 19, in <module>
    urlpatterns = path('', 'google.searchengine.views.search'),
  File "C:\Users\Konjo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 73, in _path
    raise TypeError('view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().')
TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().

Answer (score 0):

the django url dispatcher has changed since django 2.0

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('articles/2003/', views.special_case_2003),
    path('articles/<int:year>/', views.year_archive),
    path('articles/<int:year>/<int:month>/', views.month_archive),
    path('articles/<int:year>/<int:month>/<slug:slug>/', views.article_detail),
]
```

EDIT...
in your case:

```
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('/', google.searchengine.views.search),
]
```

but you need to import the corresponding view, because there is no **google.searchengine.views.search** import in your urls.py

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/

Comment: Returns:

 File "C:\Users\Konjo\konjo_search\konjo_search\urls.py", line 18, in <module>
    from . import views
ImportError: cannot import name 'views' from 'konjo_search' (C:\Users\Konjo\konjo_search\konjo_search\__init__.py)

Comment: I have edited my comment, try with that, and check the correct view path

Comment: ummm that tutorial  is writen in python2 if you dont know how to translate to python3, I recommend to get back to python2 in order to make it work

Comment: check it: http://www.connellybarnes.com/code/web_search/
it says, the plugin is compatible with python2... it's mandatory to use python2 in your project...

Comment: Running python 2 now, similar issue.

Comment: why you don't try with another search plugin, there are many of them in github. that tutorial is very old and I think it is using a deprecated version of django...

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
from google.searchengine.views import search
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('', search)
]
```

Edit:
If you followed the guide I think it would actually be:

```
from searchengine.views import search
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('', search)
]
```

Comment: There are going to be a lot of problems with this tutorial if you are using python 3.

Comment: Running python 2.7 now. Returns:   File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\Konjo\google\google\urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.urls import path
ImportError: cannot import name path

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have a project called google and app called searchengine, (as per the tutorial)
do this,

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.search, name='search'),
]
```

Comment: Returns:

 File "C:\Users\Konjo\google\google\urls.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.urls import path
ImportError: cannot import name path

Comment: path is present in django 2.x on wards. Make sure you have upgraded django version.